# Powershell Array length

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement

I have written the below to error trap an empty array and it isn't working. Any ideas on the syntax I need?

```
$inputstring =   "MyOtherFile.rdl" "MyFile.rdl"
$cleanstring =  $inputstring.replace(""" """,";")
$filearray = $inputstring.split(";")

if (echo @($filearray).length = "0")


{$filearray.length
'No Files Selected'

exit}

else
{$filearray.length}
```

It is returning 2 for the array length but is still tripping the 1st part of the IF and saying no files selected.

Comment: Hi Jon, do you have any explanation as to why you edited my question please?

Comment: The first line throws already an error. Are you sure you executed the code you posted?

Comment: it doesn't throw an error when called from inside the source system I am using. It is an array of all the files currently selected - yes I have executed it.

Comment: Powershell's [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) are `-eq`, `-ne`, `-gt` and so on.

Comment: @DaveEdmonds If `$inputstring` is already an array, you should comma separate the two strings: `$inputstring  =  "MyOtherFile.rdl", "MyFile.rdl"`. Then you can also directly evaluate the length like `$inputstring.Length -eq 0`.

Comment: Your code is not PowerShell. Is it possible to run PowerShell Core on your system? I am a bit confused why you would use `echo` in a condition. Otherwise, the equality operator for bash is `==`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```bsh
function ValidateArrayLength([string[]] $files) {
    if ($files.length -eq 0) {
        $files.length
        'No Files Selected'
        exit
    }
    else {
        $files.length
    }
}

$filearray = @("MyOtherFile.rdl", "MyFile.rdl")
ValidateArrayLength -files $filearray

$filearray = @()
ValidateArrayLength -files $filearray
```